# Swift: Need to move data stored using a button to another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift

Using a button to collect a phone number and then reading and storing the phone number under the button function.

```
@IBAction func viewRewardsButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {    
    view.endEditing(true)
    // Validate format
    let phoneNumberInput = phoneInput.text
}
```

Is there a better way to store the phone number `phoneNumberInput` and get it to another `UIViewController`?

I currently can't get the other `UIViewController` to recognize the variables stored under the `@IBAction` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `UserDefaults`:

```
// Set phone number
UserDefaults.standard.set(phoneInput,text, forKey: "phoneNumber")

// Get phone number
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "phoneNumber")
```

Or if you want to segue at the same time that you´re clicking the button use this:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showVC2", sender: phoneNumber.text)

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "showVC2") {
        if let phoneNumber = sender as? String {
            let vc = segue.destination as! YourSecondVC
            vc.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        }
    }
}
```

So you basically create the segue and declare a variable for phoneNumber in your second VC so that you can pass the value to it.

Comment: or store the number in a class-level variable within the initial class, and pass the data as part of the segue at a later stage.

Comment: @Russell, that´s also an alternative, but I assumed that OP wanted to segue immediately on button click.

Comment: Thanks guys, i got it. Yes i wanted immediately on click. I got it with similar code as above. I was stuck for a couple hours but of course 15 minutes after this post the caffeine finally hit me and I started thinking again.

Comment: I cant yet.. dumb reputation rating requirement. But i do appreciate the answer! I will up vote later when i can but i did check it

Answer (score 0):

Your `phoneNumberInput` variable is only stored in the scope of your action handler method `viewRewardsButtonTapped`, so once this method is left the value is lost. You should add a member variable (`var phoneNumber: String?`) to your class and use this for storing the value. Then, when you open the next view controller, you can pass the value in as a parameter.

If you are using storyboard segues (which I assume), you have to implement `performSegue withIdentifier`, cast the destination view controller to the concrete type and set the value (e.g. `targetVC.phoneNumber = self.phoneNumber`).